# AEM CQ Richtext xtype

Tags: xml, aem, richtext, xtype

I have custom RTEplugin. For `dailog.xml` it works like:

```
<RTE
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="rte"
    name="./rte"
    xtype="richtext">
    <listeners
      jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
      destroy="function() {this.el.dom={};}"/>
    <rtePlugins
      jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
      path="/apps/components/content/rteconfig/rtePlugins.infinity.json"
      xtype="cqinclude"/>
</RTE>
```

But i should replace it on JS:
I will try to do something like:

```
var rte = {
                fieldLabel: 'rte',
                name: 'rte',
                xtype: 'richtext',
                listeners: {
                    destroy: function(){
                        this.el.dom={};
                    }
                },
                rtePlugins : {
                    path: '/apps/components/content/rteconfig/rtePlugins.infinity.json',
                    xtype:'cqinclude'
                }
            };
```

But it not works - The path has not been applied. Maybe someone knows? It was incorrectly declared path or was incorrectly declared a plugin